# $(a, b, c)$, such that $a,b,c\geq 0$ are integers and $b = 2a$, $c = 3a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Recursive function for the set of triples $(a, b, c)$, such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are non-negative integers and $b = 2a$ and $c = 3a$.

Comment: What is the question being asked...? Can't you obtain the only valid triples by plugging in $a = 0,1,2,\dots$

Answer (score 0):

The set is { (a,2a,3a) : 0 <= a, a integer }.

Why would anyone need a recursive definition?
(i(0), j(0), k(0)) = (0,0,0).
(i(n + 1), j(n + 1), k(n + 1)) = (i(n) + 1, j(n) + 2, k(n) + 3)

Comment: It's a set of triples: for this particular set, some of the elements are (0, 0, 0), (1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 6), etc. This is not a finite set.

Comment: That's what I wrote.  @HaiderBokhari